Ethereum RETURN opocde memory expansion cost
I am currently implementing a version of the ethereum EVM and am running into a problem when implementing memory expansion costs for the RETURN opcode. When returning data from addresses outside the currently allocated memory I'm adding the standard memory expansion costs which causes some test cases to pass from the official ethereum tests. However, if I remove this cost some tests that previously failed now pass and others that passed now fail. My question is what is the expected behaviour in this case.
